# How to calculate a percentage

Tags: c#, string, double, percentage

I want to calculate a percentage. My code is:

```
Bot.Log("[ KEYBOT ] The total is " + (suctrades * totaltrades ) / 100 + "% !");
```

If I do this, I only get 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cast the value to `double` before the multiplication

Comment: would it not rather be `String.Format("The total is {0:n2} %!", ((suctrades / (double)totaltrades) * 100.0))`?? I believe your base is simply false as well, unless suctrades * totaltrades cannot go above 100 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `suctrades * totaltrades` is still an `int`. The easiest way will be probably changing your code to:

```
((double)suctrades) * totaltrades/100
```

Or

```
suctrades * totaltrades/100.0
```

To force using `double` instead of `int`

Comment: On SO you don't need to thanks just mark my answer or vote it up

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Bot.Log("[ KEYBOT ] The total is " + ((double)suctrades * totaltrades ) / 100 + "% !");
```

I assume **suctrades** and **totaltrades** are not of decimal type. This should fix this due to type propagation as expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Int is an integer type; dividing two ints performs an integer division, i.e. the fractional part is truncated since it can't be stored in the result type (also int!). Decimal, by contrast, has got a fractional part. By invoking Decimal.Divide, your int arguments get implicitly converted to Decimals.

You can enforce non-integer division on int arguments by explicitly casting at least one of the arguments to a floating-point type, e.g.: 100.0m this is casting to decimal !

```
decimal result = suctrades * totaltrades/100.0m
```