# Increase Color Value onclick from black to red Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-framework-7

i'm working on a app and I'm trying to create a function that increases the color from black to red gradually of a number.
For example the user chooses a number that goes from 0 to 100 that means he can click the button 100 times until he receives a messages saying that he can't click anymore, and I would like the color of the number getting always more red until the counter goes to the end.

Number 0 = black -> Number 100 = full red.

Here is the function that adds a number onclick:

```
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0" readonly="readonly"></input>

i = 0; // Default value (it's the number that shows on the counter)
x = 0; // It's the max value the user sets for the counter

function adicionar()
{
 if( i < x)
 {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('inc').value = i;
 }
}
```

This is what i have tried:

```
a = x * 50 / 100
b = x * 80 / 100
c = x * 100 / 100

if(i == a){
 var $$ = Dom7;
 $$('body').addClass('yellow');
}
if(i == b){
 var $$ = Dom7;
 $$('body').addClass('red');
}
if(i == c){
 var $$ = Dom7;
 $$('body').addClass('red2');
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?  Setting the element colour?  Calculating a percentage of 255? Calculating the difference between input value and 100?  Determining what value was input?  Needs more clarity as to your exact problem, or are you just hoping someone will write the whole thing for you?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to change the color of the text when the counter gets to like 50% it's a light red, 80% it's more darker and 100% full red, but i don't know to get that information. I tried this a = x * 50 / 100 - if(i == a){...} but it only works with even numbers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191908/how-to-calculate-a-percentage

Comment: As black=red@0 and full red = red@255, your red amount would be: (x * 255)/100 (times first as they're integers) applied to the red, `$('body').css("background-color", 'rgb(r, 0, 0)')`

Comment: If you want to consider custom coloring based on your range value, have a look at this implentation. https://jsfiddle.net/jdmschgq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let userNumberChoosen = 10 //asuuming here as 0 to 10, can be any number
let start = 0;
const changeColor = () => {
    const r = 255 * start/userNumberChoosen;
    const b = 0;
    const newColor ='rgb('+r+','+b+',0)';
 document.getElementById("change").style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  start += 1.  //increment color step
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div> Notice my background color </div>
    <div id="change">.</div> 
    <button onClick="changeColor()">Change background</button>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming x is the limit, function `obtenerRojo` will return a shade of red.

```
let i = 0, x = 100;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener ('click', () => {
  adicionar ()
});
function obtenerRojo ( index, limit ) {
    return Math.floor(index*255/limit);
}
function adicionar() {
  if( i < x ) {
      i++;
      const inp = document.getElementById('inc');
      inp.value = i;
      const red = obtenerRojo ( i, x );
      inp.style.color = `rgb(${red},0,0)`;;
  } else {
    alert('limit exceeded');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let maxlength = 500
let textLength = textValue.length //textValue is on change input text

let multiple = ((maxlength - textLength) * 10) / maxlength;
let gnb = 15.2 * multiple;
let colorShift = "rgb(152," + gnb + "," + gnb + ")"; 
//color shifts from gray to red
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.